# Best practice for storing counters in meteor.js

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I used to store counters inside the User document. But I often check the existing of Meteor.user() before running some code.
The counters update every second so the code reruns over and over again.
Is creating a separate Counters collection a way to solve this problem?

Counters example:

```
counters: {
  generatedDocs: {
    total: 482360
  }
  posts: {
    total: 23
  },
  comments: {
    total: 200
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  If you want to store the counter variable across multiple sessions and/or have it visible for multiple users, you want to make a counter collection in the database and work with that.  If you just want counters for one session, then you can store them in a variable on the window object.

Comment: I want counters to denormalize the mongodb. To use them instead of Collection.find().count() method (to show statistics). So they must be stored inside the database

Comment: Are the counters conceptually bound to any other data in your database?  If not, then definitely create a new collection.  Create a new collection for any discrete group of data

Comment: It's an information about user that shows up on the profile page.
I can't subscribe to whole list of documents but I need their number. 
So may be a Counters collection with the 'userId' key is a solution.

Comment: why can't you just add a coutner property to the existing user document:  something like Users.insert({counter: numTimes});

Comment: I often check the existing of Meteor.user() before running some code. And the user document will update every second if the file generator will be on. So the code will reload because of meteor's reactivity

Answer (score 0):

If this is for one session you can use the [Session](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session) api of Meteor. And as Goodword said, if this is across sessions and users you can store the counters in its own collection. If what you are counting are own collections you can also use the [count()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/count) function if it fits your use case.